# Should I use background thread when saving image to android device?

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, android-asynctask

I need to capture an Image from a View(android.webkit.WebView) and save it as a PNG file on the android device.

Should I save the image using an AsyncTasks to avoid blocking the UI thread?

What code should I leave out of AsyncTask doInBackground method?

Code:

```
    private void getWebScreenshot() {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    String filePath = storageDir + "/" + imageFileName + ".png";

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // Log.i(LOGTAG, "External Storage Available");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            // Log.i(LOGTAG,"storageDir does not exists");
            if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                // Log.d(LOGTAG, "Failed to create the directory");
            }
        }

        // Create bitmap screen capture
        Bitmap bitmap;
        View sview = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        sview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sview.getDrawingCache());
        sview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        File imageFile = new File(filePath);

        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fout);
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();

            // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
            // immediately available to the user.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{imageFile.toString()}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            // Log.i(LOGTAG, "ExternalStorage Scanned " + path + ":");
                            // Log.i(LOGTAG, "ExternalStorage > uri: " + uri);
                        }
                    });

            // Log.i(LOGTAG, "Success");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely you have to do this in a background thread. All I/O operations have to be done on background threads because there is no guarantee how fast the operation will finish - it can take from milliseconds to minutes (this is a very bad bad bad case). All access to the storage, to databases, to web resources, etc. have to be done on a background thread.

Using multiple threads can lead to synchronization problems. Move to the separate thread only the code that does the I/O operation.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1. the answer is yes, you don't want to block your UI thread.
   better solution will be to save the image in other thread and meanwhile inform the user, so he will know the image is saving(enable the button, loader gif...).
2. everything can be in the thread accept the part you take the timestamp because you can accidentally create two files with the same name